# How to get path of DLL after loading it into a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, listbox

I am creating an application that would load DLLs into a ListBox. It does this by the user pressing a button then the user can open files, and load them into the listview.

So it would look something like this.

[image]

The DLL is added in by opening the users files then they add it in themselves and into the ListBox.

My question is. How does I get the exact Path to the MaterialSkin.dll, and put it into a string when someone selected MaterialSkin.dll in the ListBox?

```
 private void materialFlatButton3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) //button used to load the DLL into the ListBox.
            {
                OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
                OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "DLL Files|*.dll";
                OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Dll File";
                if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    // put the selected result in the global variable
                    fullFileName = new List<String>(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames);

                    // add just the names to the listbox
                    foreach (string fileName in fullFileName)
                    {
                        listBox2.Items.Add(fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1));
                    }


                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible I would adjust your OpenFileDialog1 to grab the path when it grabs the file name. Then, using a dictionary instead of a list you can show display member that is just the .dll name, while the value member can be the dir or the dir / .dll name.

Here's what that might look like in the snippet you posted:

```
 private void materialFlatButton3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
//button used to load the DLL into the ListBox.
            {
                OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
                OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "DLL Files|*.dll";
                OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Dll File";
                if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    // put the selected result in the global variable
                    // ~~Using Dictionary instead of list~~
                    fullFileName = new Dictionary<string, string>(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames);

                    // Populate Listbox from dictionary.    
                    listBox2.Datasource = fullFileName.ToList();
                    listBox2.DisplayMember = "Value";
                    listBox2.ValueMember = "Key";    
                }
            }
```

This makes the assumption you can change your OpenFileDialog1 object to return a dictionary instead of a list.

Then you'll just use listBox2.SelectedValue to get the dir.

Answer (score 0):

The exact path comes to you from OpenFileDialog1.FileNames...

So store the full path in a Dictionary with the key corresponding to the current index as you're populating the listBox.  When they select an item in the listbox, use that to do your dictionary lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a WinForms app and not WPF, then you have a couple of options.

if the 'fullFileName' variable is a class variable, then when the user selects an item in the ListBox, you can loop through the full DLL paths in the fullFileName variable until you the matching file name.

```
  private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
     string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
     foreach( var path in fullFileName) 
      { 
      if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path).Equals(curItem, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Full path = " + path); 
        break; 
        }
     }
  }
```

Another option is set the DataSource of the ListBox to a list of objects which contain both the DLL name and the full path.Then use the SelectedItemChanged event (not the SelectedIndexChanged) and the SelectedItem will point to the full path.

```
public class AssemblyItem
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public string FullPath {get;set;}
}

private void materialFlatButton3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
  // Use your existing code to get the selection of DLLs

  List<AssemblyItem> items = new List<AssemblyItem>();
  foreach (string fileName in fullFileName)
  {
  items.Add(new AssemblyItem() 
     { 
      Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName),
      FullPath = fileName
     };
   }

  listBox1.DataSource = items;
  listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
  listBox1.ValueMember = "FullPath";
  listBox1.BindData();
```

}

BTW, I would recommend using the methods in System.IO.Path to get the file names from the path instead of using LastIndexOf.